# Lookup an EJB by local interface in a multi module project

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi, service-locator

I'm trying to made EJB lookups by ServiceLocator without hardcoded the JNDI name, using  only the local interface name. The problem is that the EJBs are distributed in other modules (JARs). Per example, I have this scenario:

**project-xxx**:

```
@Stateless
class EjbXBean implements EjbX {

}
```

Registered by the container with the JNDI: `java:global/project-xxx/EjbXBean`

**project-yyy**:

```
@Stateless
class EjbYBean implements EjbY {

}
```

Registered by the container with the JNDI: `java:global/project-yyy/EjbYBean`

EjbX and EjbY are both `@Local`. I would like to get the EJB only doing this in another module:

```
EjbX ejbx = ServiceLocator.lookup(EjbX.class);
EjbY ejby = ServiceLocator.lookup(EjbY.class);
```

But I don't know what is the module (project-yyy or project-xxx) only with the local interface inside the ServiceLocator. I can't only do the lookup using the entire JNDI name with the module name:

```
EjbX ejbx = ServiceLocator.lookup("java:global/project-yyy/EjbXBean");
EjbY ejby = ServiceLocator.lookup("java:global/project-yyy/EjbYBean");
```

I'm trying to figure out what is the best practice in this case, because I don't know if the hardcoded the JNDI name is a good practice or not in the JavaEE world.

I'm using OpenEjb 4.7.4 for development and integration tests, Wildfly 10.1.0 for production.

## Update

I can to this using CDI in Wildfly 10.1.0:

```
@Override
public Object lookup(Class<?> type, Annotation... annotations) throws NamingException {
    BeanManager manager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
    Iterator<Bean<?>> beans = manager.getBeans(type, annotations).iterator();

    if (!beans.hasNext()) {
        throw new NamingException("CDI BeanManager cannot find an instance of requested type " + type.getName());
    }
    Bean<?> bean = beans.next();
    CreationalContext<?> ctx = manager.createCreationalContext(bean);
    return manager.getReference(bean, type, ctx);
}
```

And to call:

```
MyClass.lookup(EjbX.class);
```

But I would not like to use CDI because [I had some problems to put this to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538143/problems-with-cdi-in-setup-for-functional-testing-with-tomee-or-openejb-jetty) in an embeddable container (OpenEJB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need different modules? Having all in one WAR would allow you to just `@Inject` the Beans. (You only need a `beans.xml` in every war that contains managed beans)

I am not sure if the standardization of the naming works with openejb and wildfly. since both are ejb 3.1 it should but did you check if your names adhere to the standard?. I had in the past problems when using Queues and Topics. perhaps [jboss naming ejb3.1](http://planet.jboss.org/post/ejb3_1_global_jndi_access_a_portable_jndi_naming_scheme_for_ejbs) can help.

To make sure the names are usable, perhaps you should consider using `arquillian` for tests. 
But I would get rid of this Namingservice issues with local beans at all.

Also, I would not use openejb for testing. I know it is embeddable but the differences are great. Another CDI-Container, possibly eclipselink instead of hibernate. Both make a great difference. I would not test on those and deploy in wildfly.

If you want something embeddable based on Weld and using hibernate perhaps consider [cdi-unit](https://github.com/BrynCooke/cdi-unit) or [ejb-cdi-unit](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit) (ok that one is my project, so I am not completely impartial ;-) )

Comment: Hi! I'm using OpenEJB to make a transition from another unknown EJB container (called MyContainer, that uses Jetty to WebApp). He is used for development and Selenium tests too, in a setup very similar with this: http://tomee.apache.org/functional-testing-with-openejb,-jetty-and-selenium.html (unique example that I found with OpenEJB and Jetty). I can put this to work in the project using full JNDI names, but now we are migrating to Java8/Wildfly and nothing works anymore, because the lookup for EJBs are using BeanManager and @Local interface (I change OpenEJB to TomEE, for the CDI).

Comment: Hello, if you try to just test your rest-webservice, there are quite good alternatives using Weld, perhaps look at [ex7-simplerest](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/tree/master/examples/ex7-simplerest). Concerning lookup, I yet did not understand, what the real problem is. How did the old application weave those modules together. JNDI, I presume. Why can't you let CDI scan the beans and put everything together by itself, without doing any lookups?

Comment: Yes, by JNDI. In the new version they stop to use JNDI and now are using only CDI to get the EJBs, but we are have some problems (https://stackoverflow.com/q/45538143/2387977) and I'm trying to use JNDI again and leaves this CDI problem for the future. You will understand the whole scenario in this another SO question :)

Comment: As I understand now, you need to use both versions in the future: openejb as well as Weld(Wildfly). And you decided, to fix the OpenEjb-Version. But, if you need, in the end, to switch completely to Wildfly, I would avoid trying to fix problems introduced by the intermediate step to tomee.

Comment: You are right. I'm trying to made CDI work, but I need a plan B too, because we have some deadlines.